# RGB value manipulation not working as intended (Verilog)

Tags: verilog

I am writing code for an entity that takes in RGB values, averages them, then outputs the altered data.

My code looks like this:

```
module RGBAVG (
   input            clk,
   input            rst_n,
   input      [9:0] iVGA_R,
   input      [9:0] iVGA_G,
   input      [9:0] iVGA_B,
   output reg [9:0] oVGA_R,
   output reg [9:0] oVGA_G,
   output reg [9:0] oVGA_B
 );

 integer avg;
 integer count;
 integer sum;
 initial begin
     count = 0;
     sum = 0;
     avg = 0; 
end

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin

  if (!rst_n) begin //reset
     sum = 0;
     count = 0;
     oVGA_R <= {10{1'b0}};
     oVGA_G <= {10{1'b0}};
     oVGA_B <= {10{1'b0}};
   end
   else begin //get RGB values from pixel, prepare for next avg evaluation
     count = (count + 1)%307200; //640*480 = 307200
     sum = sum + (iVGA_R + iVGA_G + iVGA_B)/3;
     if (count == 0) begin
        avg = sum/307200; //update avg
        sum = 0;
        end

 oVGA_R <= avg;
 oVGA_G <= avg;
 oVGA_B <= avg;
   end
 end

 endmodule
```

However, when I upload the code, all I get is a black screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to write a testbench and simulate your design. Don't bother trying it on hardware until your simulation works.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'compile', do you mean synthesize for a specific target? Are you trying to simulate this, or load it onto an FPGA?

I cannot say exactly what that error means, though I might make a suggestions that may make it go away.

Your logic is somewhat strange to me and probably not synthesizeable. You have an asynchronous reset to your always block, and you're saying that:

> Anytime I assert this asynchronous reset, increment the value of count and sum

This kind of construct does not really exist in typical hardware, your asynchronous reset should do only one thing, which is to reset the state of all your flops. Therefore I recommend to move all this:

```
count = (count + 1)%307200;
sum = sum + (iVGA_R + iVGA_G + iVGA_B)/3;
if (count == 0) begin
    avg = sum/307200;
    sum = 0;
end
```

into the `else` clause so that it doesn't try to write new register values on asynchronous reset. I suspect that this has something to do with your error. You probably want to reset the count and sum as well on reset, is my guess.

Comment: I took your advice and moved the code into the else clause, and changed count and sum to reg type variables. Currently I'm simply compiling the code and not loading it onto my FPGA.

Oh, and I also forgot some of my reset code. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Sorry couldn't tell from your comment, did that fix the issue? If not I might recommend editing your updated code into the question.

Comment: `integer X` is identical to `reg signed [31:0] X`.

Comment: @Adam12 - Thanks for clarifying, I wasn't sure. I did see this note in [this image](http://images.elektroda.net/1_1219987816.jpg) which I found posted on EDABoard which was claimed to be from the verilog 2001 spec, which states : "integer is for quantities not regarded as hardware registers", so I wasn't sure if it was discouraged.

Comment: My code compiles but doesn't work as intended. I want to take in the RGB values of 640x480 pixels, average them out and fill the entire screen with that average. However, when I upload the code above, my screen is just black. Can someone help me with this?